# Java - weird generics behavior with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, type-erasure

I was trying to implement some kind of custom serialization with reflection, and then I found out that you just cannot cast `A[]` to `B[]` if A isn't a subtype of B even if all the elements in the array are subtypes of B (It should work because of type erasing because at the end of the day both `a[]` and `b[]` are `Object[]`).

here is an example of what I mean:

```java
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Foo().testGenerics();
    }


    public LinkedList<String> strList;
    public String[] strArr;

    public void testGenerics() throws Exception {

        LinkedList<Object> objList = new LinkedList<Object>();
        objList.add("foo");


        Object[] objArr = new Object[1];
        objArr[0] = "bar";

        Foo.class.getField("strList").set(this, objList);

        System.out.println("list[0]  = " + strList.get(0));
        System.out.println("list len = " + strList.size());

        Foo.class.getField("strArr").set(this, objArr);

        System.out.println("arr[0]  = " + strArr[0]);
        System.out.println("arr len = " + strArr.length);

    }

}
```

In this example the list works fine but the array throws an exception at the line that tries to set it.

is there any reason arrays ignore type erasing, and is there any good way to create an array and a list for a given type at runtime?

Comment: "is there any reason arrays ignore type erasing" Because arrays are not generic. They are arrays...

Comment: The variable `strArr` is not defined generically - it is a `String[]`.  So at runtime, you cannot assign an `Object[]` reference to that variable.  The `objList` is just a `List` at runtime due to type-erasure.  That's why you can use reflection to stick any List in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays and generics are very different things. Generics are erased at runtime because the JVM doesn't know about them. However, the JVM *does* know about arrays. If you search in the [JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html) for "array", you'll see that [section 3.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.9) is titled "Arrays". But you can't find anything about generics, or parameterised types. You can read section 3.9 in more detail to find out just how much the JVM knows about arrays. The Java Language Specification also talks about [arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html) and [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5) in very different sections.

Therefore, the JVM at runtime, can and does try to maintain the type safety of arrays, and stops you from assigning `Object[]` to `String[]`. This is analogous to the Java Compiler trying to maintain the type safety of `LinkedList`s at compile time by stopping you from assigning a `LinkedList<Object>` to a `LinkedList<String>`. It's not like the latter is somehow "safe to do" at runtime, it's just that the runtime doesn't know enough to stop you.

> is there any good way to create an array and a list for a given type at runtime?

Given the `Class<?> clazz` and the `length`, you can create an array of it by:

```
Object o = Array.newInstance(clazz, length);
```

But having to do this smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... Make sure you know what you are doing.

You can create a list using the way you are using right now. It's not type safe, but that's a flaw of JVM/Java.

Comment: ah I see, Good to know that array are not generics, Ill look into that `Array.newInstance` it might be good enough if Ill find a way to extract the type of an array at runtime.